# Why does reversing a string function require range(len(string)-1)

Tags: python

I'm taking a Python course on Codecademy. I've been tasked with writing a function that returns a given string in reverse. I struggled with this question so I had to look up the answer, which is:

```
def reverse_string(word): 
    reverse = ""
    for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):
        reverse += word[i]
    return reverse
```

I don't see why the function `range` should have as its starting value `len(word)-1` and `-1` as its end value. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Let's say my word is "Hello". Doesn't `len(word)-1` mean that it will start iterating over the string at index 3 (`"l"`) instead of index 4?

Comment: `'some string'[::-1]` so just do `def reverse_string(word): return word[::-1]`

Comment: What is len(word) if word is "hello"?

Comment: If you iterated for the full length, it would attempt to add a word from an empty list.

Comment: `len("Hello")` is 5 so `len("Hello") - 1` is the 4 you want.

Comment: what does :: mean?

Comment: `::` or rather `[::-1]` means default values `start`, `end` in `[start:end:step]` And this is `slicing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the string we want to reverse is `"Hello"`

| Index | Character |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | H |
| 1 | e |
| 2 | l |
| 3 | l |
| 4 | o |

We want a range starting at `4`, and reducing by `1` until it reaches the value `0`.

Notice that `4 = len("Hello") - 1`, which is why that's the `start` argument.

We want to go down by one each time, so `step = -1`.

We want to include `0` in our range, and since `range` returns a semi-open interval, the `end` argument must be one `step` beyond our required last value, so `end = -1`

To verify this, let's do

```
mystr = "Hello"
for i in range(len(mystr)-1, -1, -1):
    print(i)
```

outputs

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a reasonable alternative way of looking at the problem.

Many other programming languages do not natively support negative indexing, so it would not seem as natural to think of `-1` as the last index.

Consider:

```
>>> list(range(5, -1, -1))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> list(range(-1, -7, -1))
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]
```

These are not at all the same lists, but in the string "hello!":

```
>>> ['hello!'[i] for i in range(5, -1, -1)]
['!', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
>>> ['hello!'[i] for i in range(-1, -7, -1)]
['!', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
```

they both would reverse it.

Comment: The question seems to have nothing to do with negative indexing though.

Comment: "–1 as its end value. Shouldn't it be the other way around?" Implies that he thinks it should start at `–1`

Answer (score 0):

If your `word` is **"Hello"**, `len(word)` becomes `len("Hello")`, which is 5. Your for loop starts iterating from 5-1, i.e. **4** and continues till one step before -1, i.e. **0**.

Note that `range()` function does not include the last element.

Here's an illustration of your for loop-

```
i value
4   o
3   l
2   l
1   e
0   h

Output - "olleh"
```