# “list index out of range” with a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am running the below code it works like a charm for few days and now I am facing the following error message: “list index out of range” related to:

```
for i in range(item_count, 0, -1):
    message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]
```

this code was running perfectly for weeks and I can fix it just by replacing the calculated item_count value with the same one -1 not really sure why it worked and stopped working ?

many thanks :) !

```
import win32com.client

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = 'Enter your email address'  # e.g. 'good.employee@importantcompany.com'
ITER_FOLDER = 'Enter the Outlook folder name which emails you would like to iterate through'  # e.g. 
'IterationFolder'
MOVE_TO_FOLDER = 'Enter the Outlook folder name where you move the processed emails'  # e.g 
'ProcessedFolder'
SAVE_AS_PATH = 'Enter the path where to dowload attachments'  # e.g.r'C:\DownloadedCSV'
EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING = 'Enter the sub-string to search in the email subject'  # e.g. 'Email to 
download'


def find_download_csv_in_outlook():
    out_app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
    out_namespace = out_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    out_iter_folder = out_namespace.Folders[EMAIL_ACCOUNT].Folders[ITER_FOLDER]
    out_move_to_folder = out_namespace.Folders[EMAIL_ACCOUNT].Folders[MOVE_TO_FOLDER]

    char_length_of_search_substring = len(EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING)

    # Count all items in the sub-folder
    item_count = out_iter_folder.Items.Count

    if out_iter_folder.Items.Count > 0:
        for i in range(item_count, 0, -1):
             message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]

            # Find only mail items and report, note, meeting etc items
            if '_MailItem' in str(type(message)):
                print(type(message))
                if message.Subject[0:char_length_of_search_substring] == EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING \
                        and message.Attachments.Count > 0:
                    for attachment in message.Attachments:
                        if attachment.FileName[-3:] == 'csv':
                            attachment.SaveAsFile(SAVE_AS_PATH + '\\' + attachment.FileName)
                            message.Move(out_move_to_folder)
    else:
        print("No items found in: {}".format(ITER_FOLDER))


if __name__ == '__main__':
     find_download_csv_in_outlook()
```

Comment: Python list indices are zero-based. A list of length `4` has indices `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. You need to iterate from `len(list) - 1` to zero (both inclusive), so you need to do `range(len(list) - 1, -1, -1)`. See this similar recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67593572/843953

Comment: Are you sure it worked? `range(5, 0, -1)` starts at `5` and ends at `1` and it is very likely that `out_iter_folder.Items[i]` is out of range on the first iteration since lists are `0-based` and would expect indexes starting at `4` and ending at `0`.

Comment: I doubt that the code that you posted was working fine and then inexplicably stopped working. You must have introduced a bug in some edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range will go from `item_count`(included) to `0`(excluded). So, you have to loop it from `item_count-1` to `-1` as the indexing of the list starts from `0` not `1`.

```py
for i in range(item_count-1, -1, -1):
    message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]
```

OR

```py
for i in reversed(range(0,item_count)):
    message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]
```